# How to Import and Export Service Desk Projects from Production Environment to Development Environment in Jira? Thanks

Tags: jira-agile, unified-service-desk

We’re looking at testing some additional plugins with a potential to buying.  I was wondering how easy it is to duplicate a Service Desk instance for testing but remove the email interfaces to ensure nothing is sent out or received by it, can someone please advise? Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify the details of your Service Desk installation? Is it self hosted or on the Atlassian cloud? Are you using the default mail system from JIRA/Service Desk?

Comment: we are using the Atlasssian cloud and we are using the default mail system from Jira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cloud based installations, Atlassian recommends to order the smallest user tier for such stage-envrionemtns. Afterwards you have to copy your data using the export/import functionality of JIRA to populate your production data to your staging or testing environment.

Have a look at these pages:

- [atlassian-cloud-staging-and-testing-environment](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeval/other-atlassian-evaluator-resources/atlassian-cloud-staging-and-testing-environment)
- [import-and-export-data](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/import-and-export-data-873871368.html)

Comment: Thank you Andreas and if it is on hosted jira then what will be the process to export/ import service desk instance? Thanks

Comment: Hi Santosh, please have a look at the official documentation: 
[Importing and exporting data](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-and-exporting-data-776636740.html)